# npm ERR! code ENOENT, npm ERR! errno 34

Tags: node.js, npm

This is my start script for a React application.

```
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "babel-node tools/startMessage.js",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel test:watch open:src lint:watch",
    "open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/esw webpack.config.* src tools",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "test": "mocha --reporter progress tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.test.js\"",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "clean-dist": "npm run remove-dist && mkdir dist",
    "remove-dist": "node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist",
    "build:html": "babel-node tools/buildHtml.js",
    "prebuild": "npm-run-all clean-dist test lint build:html",
    "build": "babel-node tools/build.js",
    "postbuild": "babel-node tools/distServer.js"
  },
```

When I run npm start, I get a long list of error.

```
npm ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.20161025.20.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "lint" "--" "--watch"
npm ERR! cwd /home/user/workspace/shareback-viewer
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.30
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! path /home/user/workspace/shareback-viewer/node_modules/lint/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34......
```

So clearly the npm script is failing because it's trying to look for the wrong path.
npm ERR! path /home/user/workspace/shareback-viewer/node_modules/lint/package.json

How can I fix this?

Comment: as an aside ... do yourself a favor and upgrade to the current release of nodejs    https://nodejs.org/en/     v7.4.0    you are using  v0.10.30

Comment: Ah oops, I guess that might be the problem. It's not parsing right.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I had this error deleting the **node_modules** and running **npm install** in again seems to do the trick, **npm start** kicks of after that little work-around. I've seem a ton of issues on GitHub about this and most people suggest using the above suggested method. If you see other npm errors you can check the [official docs for error troubleshooting](https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/common-errors). If it still occurs try **npm cache clean** command, note that you may need to add the **--force**  flag sometimes. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Delete ***node_modules*** and ***package-lock.json*** and install again